# 'Bad file descriptor', check disk found no errors

Tags: windows-7, file-corruption, file-descriptors, mts

I copied two .MTS video files from an SD card to an external drive, over USB 3.0. One file was ok, the other did not get a thumbnail and attempting to access it bsplayer froze and could not be terminated even with end process. Clicking on properties on the file made explorer freeze such that it could neither be closed by end process. Have to force restart the computer every time I attempt to access this file now. Can not delete the file either.

Renamed it to .avi. Sat VLC to fix file on load. That made VLC show the following Error:  "File reading failed: VLC could not read the file (Bad file descriptor)."

I ran check disk through Explorer > Properties > Tools > Check now. This did not find any errors.

So how can I delete or uncorrupt this file?

Comment: Do you still have the original? Try copying it again. It sounds like the file occupies corrupt sectors on the disk. Chkdsk can detect this if you enable scanning for bad sectors (which is not on by default).

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator The two files on the memory card got removed or corrupted at the same time. Camera (Panasonic UX180) can now not play the files, as it's shown as unplayable. Windows explorer does not even show these files on the memory card.  I did enable bad sector scanning when i ran check-disk.